# Gitlab CI How to run ssh (windows to windows)?

Tags: windows, ssh, gitlab, cicd

I've deployed GitLab Runner on Windows server A and want to transfer files over SSH in the CI pipeline to another Windows server B.

Both A and B have the SSH private and public keys set up, and I can execute SSH without passwords directly from the command line on A. However, when using the pipeline, it times out.

The weird thing is, if the GitLab Runner is running in the command prompt (by executing gitlab-runner.exe run), it works fine. However, when the Runner is running as a Windows service (by executing gitlab-runner.exe install), the ssh connection times out.

The official GitLab documentation only covers how to use SSH keys for Docker and Linux. I'm not sure how to proceed on Windows.

Can anyone help me with this?

---

Edit:

Ok I got some info. When the runner running in the cmd directly, it uses the account administrator. While when it running as windows service, it uses nt authority\system.

So the account should be the problem. My ssh key is created for administrator, not for system.

Well, still not find a way to solve this yet.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved.

The default account of windows service is "nt authority\system".
It can be changed to administrator in the property setting (by setting service's login account).

But ssh still has some problems when running as windows service which registered  by "gitlab-runner.exe install".

I didn't find a way to solve it. Instead, I use FireDaemon to run the GitLab Runner (specify administrator as the logon account). It works fine.